# Build XML with CSV data

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js, xml-parsing

I am trying to build out a way to "upload" a csv file locally and have it build out an xml file based on data in the csv. I need to do all of this client-side, and I'm not too fluent with JS yet. I've figured out how to extract csv data...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
       d3.select("body").append("input").attr("type", "file").attr("accept", ".csv").on("change", function() {
            var csv = d3.event.target.files[0];
                if (csv) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onloadend = function(event) {
                        var Url = event.target.result;
                        d3.csv(Url, function(data) {
                            return {
                                name: data.name,
                                latitude: data.latitude,
                                longitude: data.longitude
                            };
                        }, function(rows) {
                            console.log(rows);
                        });
                    };
                reader.readAsDataURL(csv);
                }
            })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

...and I hope to iterate through the data to build the xml. Where I would like some guidance or suggestions is how I could build out the xml and have it downloaded as a file afterwards. Would DOM be right for the job? If so, how can I have it download abc.xml after it is generated from abc.csv? I am trying to turn cvs data "SomeName,40.987654,-70.123456" into...

```
<Entry>
    <name>SomeName</name>
    <Location>
        <coordinates>-70.123456,40.987654</coordinates>
    </Location>
</Entry>
```

I hope this was clear; if not, let me know and I'll try to better elaborate!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following example as a guide. This requires NPM package [xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-parse) as a dependency.

```js
var xmlDoc = [
  {
    type: 'element',
    tagName: '?xml',
    attributes: {
      version: '1.0',
      encoding: 'UTF-8'
    },
    childNodes: [],
    innerXML: '>',
    closing: false,
    closingChar: '?'
  },
  {
    type: 'element',
    tagName: 'root',
    attributes: {},
    childNodes: [
      {
        type: 'text',
        text: 'Root Element'
      }
    ],
    innerXML: 'Root Element',
    closing: true,
    closingChar: null
  }
]
 
var xmlStr = xml.stringify(xmlDoc, 2); // 2 spaces
 
console.log(xmlStr);
```